# Breaking a long reproducible foreach loop into several smaller loops

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-foreach, reproducible-research

In R, is there a way to break a single, long parallel for loop into several shorter loops and still keep them reproducible and identical?

I tried to do this with the `doRNG` and `foreach` packages, but when I use several short loops right after each other, the RNG seeds are not the same as when using one long loop and the results therefore differ.

====

Example code

```
library(doRNG)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

# one loop
set.seed(123) 
x1 <- foreach(i = 1:4) %dorng% sample(100, 5)

# several loops
set.seed(123) 
x2 <- foreach(i = 1:2) %dorng% sample(100, 5)
# ... possibly doing other computations and then resetting seed ...
x3 <- foreach(i = 1:2) %dorng% sample(100, 5)

all.equal(c(x1), c(x2, x3)) # component 3 and 4 differ
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the "other computations" take more time than the sampling. So maybe generating the samples sequentially and then doing the other computations in parallel could be a solution?